# Prevent <br> tag at end of input string with PHP

Tags: php

I want to eliminate the **LAST** `<br>` tag that can mess up my web display after the end of the user's input string. Apparently I messed something up on this simple task and stuck with it for some time now...
Here is my code, please help me check what did I do wrong.

```
<?php
// Cut down Strange <br> tag
$content = "This is some string here<br>";
$content .= "And I want it to be on seperate line so yeah!!<br>";
$content .= "The last br tag is not suppose to be here<br>";
$checkBRtag = substr($content, -4);
if (strcmp($checkBRtag, "<br>") == 0)
    $result = substr($content, 0, -4);
?>
```

Strangely the result is that the string always get cut out the last 4 character without checking if it is `<br>` tag or not. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by I'm not excepting answers? I vote up on the answer below because it makes me realized my own mistake. so yeah...

Comment: all fine and dandy if you vote them up, yet by not closing the question(s) still leaves them open and considered as unanswered. People may think it is still open and may want to submit more answers, up until one has the green tick next to it.

Comment: oh ... sr I dont know that, can you show me how to close this discussion?

Comment: You're welcome. I removed  [SOLVED] from the title. marking an answer as the correct one marks it as solved so there's no further action needed ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You general approach works for me, maybe you can simplify it, so that you *always* get the result in your variable `$result`:

```
<?php
$content = "This is some string here<br>";
$content .= "And I want it to be on seperate line so yeah!!<br>";
$content .= "The last br tag is not suppose to be here<br>";
$result = 
    (strcmp(substr($content, -4), "<br>") == 0) 
    ? substr($content, 0, -4) 
    : $content;

var_dump($result);
```

The output obviously is:

`string(119) "This is some string here<br>And I want it to be on seperate line so yeah!!<br>The last br tag is not suppose to be here"`

---

However I wonder if there is a better approach to this... Looking at the way you construct your `$content` in your code example it appears that you already have your text lines in an array like structure, so as separate lines. If so, then easiest would be not to append a `<br>` tag to each line at all, but to use the `implode()` function for this. That way you will not create that trailing tag in the first place, eliminating the need to remove it later...

Comment: oh yah... I save it as the wrong PHP file... Thank you thou.. Thought I was wrong on the code that I didn't notice the biggest mistake

Comment: Is this userinput? Whant happens with a '<br />' or'<br\0>'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

**Specially in your case**, If you know in which string you want to remove all **HTML** tags including with `<br>` tag.

```
$content = "This is some string here<br>";
$content .= "And I want it to be on seperate line so yeah!!<br>";
// below line remove all HTML tags from string with <br> tag.
$content .= strip_tags("The last br tag is not suppose to be here<br>");
```

Comment: This removes _all_ `<br>` tags from the text which is not what the OP asks for...

Comment: And if that string contains _other_ html tags (e.g. <em>...</em>)? You are using a sledgehammer to work on jewels...

Comment: I have mentioned in answer. "Specially in your case".

Comment: What you call "in your case" obviously only is an example given by the OP. You do not know what tags may be contained. Answers and tools have to be robust against such stuff...